# Expected infimum of a 1d random walk

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk

Consider a simple symmetric random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ starting from $0$,
$S_n$. Let $I_n := \inf\{S_0, S_1, S_2, \ldots S_n\}$. Is an explicit formula for $E[I_n]$ known?

Comment: Yes. Reflection principle. $E(I_n)\approx -E(|S_n|)$. You can have an precise formula as well.

Comment: It's not entirely fresh in my mind, but iirc this last quantity is asymptotically $-c\sqrt{n}$ for some absolute constant $c>0$ (Update: see (39) in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomWalk1-Dimensional.html, and (34-35) for non-asymptotics)

Comment: Thanks, it is known that it grows asymptotically as $\sqrt{n}$, but I am interested in the explicit formula, in case there is an easy one.

Comment: Then check the keywords `reflection principle` mentioned in the first comment.